# Plus-que-parfait du subjonctif

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, conditionnel, mode-grammatical, temps-composés

Prenons cette proposition hypothétique qui emploie le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif :

> Si j'eusse eu la possibilité, je t'eusse prêté ma voiture.

Je sais bien que ce temps du subjonctif est très littéraire. Certains des livres de grammaire française que je possède n'en parlent même pas.

Cependant, le rencontrons-nous dans les épreuves telles que celles des concours administratifs ou du Certificat Voltaire ?

Si la réponse est affirmative, suffit-il de le reconnaître ou faut-il aussi que l'on sache l'utiliser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je ne pense pas qu'il soit nécessaire d'aller jusqu'à ce niveau de langue pour des concours administratifs ou le certificat Voltaire, qui relève déjà du registre soutenu pour les meilleurs. Savoir reconnaître le subjonctif imparfait dans une subordonnée hypothétique est largement suffisant.

Je renvoie à ceci pour plus de détails.
[Liens](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-si-subjonctif-imparfait-plus-que-parfait.909469/?hl=fr)