# Le subjonctif de l'imparfait

Tags: grammaire

The [1910 edition](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2013%3A6-7&version=LSG) Louis Segond translation of Genesis 13:6 uses *demeurassent* :

> la contrée était insuffisante pour qu'ils **demeurassent** ensemble

My copy of the 1976 edition uses *restent* :

[image: Le pays était insuffisant pour qu'ils restent ensemble]

The [2007 edition](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis%2013%3A6&version=SG21) uses *habitent*:

> La région ne suffisait pas pour qu'ils **habitent** ensemble.

Is there any particular reason to prefer the subjonctif de l'imparfait or the subjonctif du présent or is it simply a matter of updated language?

---

<sub>*P.S. Bonus item of interest for Biblical Hebrew enthusiasts would be the three different nouns and verbs used to render the Hebrew across these translations... "pays" is אָ֖רֶץ "aretz" and "rester" is ישב "yashav", the root of Sabbath.*</sub>

Comment: Apart from the answer, see also the recent questions here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29211/plus-que-parfait-du-subjonctif   and  here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29226/emploi-des-temps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays, we will rather use the subjonctif présent instead of subjonctif imparfait.

Some writers still use the subjonctif imparfait but we don't use it when we speak. As a result, people tend to use more and more the subjonctif présent in writings. It's the same for the [subjonctif plus-que-parfait](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/conjugaison/conjuguer-verbe-habiter/) (que j’eusse habité) : we will prefer the subjonctif passé (que j’aie habité).